# Can we log the `Accept-Encoding` field in request when using nginx?

Tags: nginx, logging, http-headers

I've read [ngx_http_core_module#variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables), however I cannot find the `Accept-Encoding` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$http_accept_encoding` variable is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get all the http header field throught `$http_`?

Comment: Yep.  The documentation you linked to says, "`$http_<name>`: arbitrary request header field; the last part of a variable name is the field name converted to lower case with dashes replaced by underscores"